# Swagger: How do I enable the API Key in my Play application?

Tags: playframework, swagger

In my `Play` application I've defined an `AuthorizationFilter` for Swagger like this:

```
class AuthorizationFilter extends SwaggerSpecFilter {

  def isOperationAllowed(
    operation: Operation,
    api: ApiDescription,
    params: java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[String]],
    cookies: java.util.Map[String, String],
    headers: java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[String]]): Boolean = {

    checkKey(params, headers) match {
      case true => true
      case false => {
        Logger("swagger").debug(s"authenticated: false - method: ${operation.method} - path: ${api.path}")
        if (operation.method == "GET" && api.path.indexOf("/admin") != -1) true
        else if (operation.method == "GET" && api.path.indexOf("/auth/users") != -1) true
        else false
      }
    }
  }

  def isParamAllowed(
    parameter: Parameter,
    operation: Operation,
    api: ApiDescription,
    params: java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[String]],
    cookies: java.util.Map[String, String],
    headers: java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[String]]): Boolean = {

    val isAuthorized = checkKey(params, headers)  
    if (parameter.paramAccess == Some("internal") && !isAuthorized) false
    else true
  }

  def checkKey(
    params: java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[String]],
    headers: java.util.Map[String, java.util.List[String]]): Boolean = {

    val apiKey = params.containsKey("api_key") match {
      case true => Some(params.get("api_key").get(0))
      case _ => {
        headers.containsKey("api_key") match {
          case true => Some(headers.get("api_key").get(0))
          case _ => None
        }
      }
    }

    apiKey match {
      case Some(key) if (key == "special-key") => true
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I've added the following configuration in my `conf\application.conf`:

```
api.version = "0.1"
swagger {
    api {
        basepath = "http://localhost:9000"
    }
    security {
        filter = "security.apidocs.AuthorizationFilter"
    }
}
```

... but the `AuthorizationFilter` never gets invoked. How do I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your AuthorizationFilter has defined the package security.apidocs first in your file.